# Even partitioning of nonuniform ranged data in cassandra

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, cassandra-0.7

I've got a rather tricky one, bear with me as I try not to stumble over my words here. I'm doing some research, and my group is transitioning to a cassandra database. Our research used MySQL before, but the data outgrew the database (192 million rows in memory @ 16G -- it was the only way to query the data fast enough). The data itself is kinda-sorta static. There's a whole lot of it, but any new data is a somewhat slow trickle at this point.

The data consists of a boatload of classifier-score pairs. We formulate queries for the database which basically say, "give me the top 500 for the following classifiers". Then the database returns that many scores. For example, if we ask for the top 500 scores for 2 classifiers, we get back 1000 rows (each row consisting of a classifier ID and a score -- i.e. [4, 9100]). The scores themselves are non-uniform (the distribution tends to clump toward one end of the values -- which by the way are from -10000 to 10000)

As we transition to cassandra, there are a number of requirements. First of all, we need to be able to query for the top and bottom N scores on a per-classifier basis. Normally I can see that an ordered partitioner would be appropriate for this, however like I said the scores tends to clump at the extremes (which would put too much of a burden on one node). So my first question is, how do I evenly distribute the classifier/score pairs while still being able to query for the top or bottom N.

There is a secondary requirement which pretty much screws up the first one. Sometimes it is necessary to find all scores that are *near* another score. So if I see classifier 6 with a score of 400, I might ask, show me 500 scores that are the closest to that (all within classifier 6). I'm absolutely stumped about this one. I've read that cassandra supports secondary indices (yay) but only hash type (boo - no ranges). Do we create a seperate ColumnFamily for this use case?

And finally, speed is paramount. The data is being used in an interactive GUI application. Ideally, queries should only take a few seconds. And if data all gets stuck on one particular node, it will slow things down.

We've tried all kinds of clever tricks. Our best idea was to put the data into buckets, so that the top 500 went into bucket 1, the next 500 went into bucket 2, and so on. The advantage is that to get the top 500 we just ask for bucket 1. Also all of the data WOULD be evenly distributed using a random partitioner. However since MOST of our queries are interested only in bucket 1, it would put a lot of burden on just one node (remember, if N classifiers are involved, it's actually 500 * N scores per bucket). The real disadvantage of this scheme is that it falls apart when we need to query based on nearness to a score (we'd have to do some kind of weird binary search over the buckets to find our starting value).

At this point we're running low on ideas. Everything I've seen about cassandra makes me wonder if it's even appropriate for this task. We chose it mainly because of it's horizontal scalability, which is important (much easier to add a node than to shard an RDBM). So I suppose my overall question is: how would you approach this? If cassandra, please address any of the above issues. Otherwise any insight or wisdom would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not storing the classifier as a column family row key and the score in column name. Since columns are sorted it is really fast to query the top/bottom 500 columns for a given classifier. The second type of query is also possible, when you are looking for the scores near *s* you can for instance select 500 columns before *s* and 500 columns after *s* and then filter the 500 columns near *s*.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you suggesting storing ALL scores for a given classifier under one row? I thought (perhaps incorrectly) that cassandra had a limit on the number of columns that it could hold. Each classifier right now will have about 2 million scores associated with it. Would 2 million scores, each represented as its own column, still be fast to look up?

Comment: From version 0.7 you can store up to 2 billion columns per row. I made some tests and the read performance was good. Well it was good for my needs and with only ~100000 columns.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to give that a try! Thank you very much for the insight, much appreciated.

Comment: Just an update on this, we've implemented it as you described and the performance is PHENOMENAL compared to our in-memory database implementation. Thanks SO MUCH.